# How long has the word "site" been used as a noun in English?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, nouns, linguistics

I am writing a book that takes place in the fictional past, so I'm trying to make sure the language used in my writing doesn't draw the reader back to the present because of it not fitting well with the time period of the story.
I am specifically struggling with the word "site." The characters in my book find ancient ruins, and I'm trying to figure out how the characters would talk about the place where the ruins are located, and if the word "site" is acceptable.
I remember when I was in grad school (many years ago), there was some kind of online catalog that I would use to do research on how long a word has been used with a specific meaning, but I can't remember what that website was.

Comment: Site is an old word, such as archaeological site.

Comment: The OED is available online, but only to subscribers. However, googling <[word] definition> should bring up an entry from Oxford Dictionaries which gives a brief indication of the age of a word. According to that, _site_ has been in use from late Middle English.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - It doesn't make the question inappropriate or devalue the site if the asker *doesn't know* many dictionaries contain more than definitions but also etymology and so *doesn't know* how to do the research to find the answer for themselves, especially if the person *doesn't know* what "etymology" even is, either. If it were required everyone know how to fully research EL&U questions to find the answers themselves, that's what would devalue this site as it would make this site moot, every question deleted for the asker inappropriately failing to find the answer themselves first.

Comment: What is the status of your characters? If they are senior churchmen such as abbots, bishops and deans or if they are noblemen or even masons they might well use the word 'site' as they would be used to discussing the 'sites' of major buildings such as churches, monasteries and castles. If they are peasants then they would be unlikely to be familiar with a Latin-based term of that nature. I think that a peasant would probably talk about 'the place where I am going to build the new cowshed'

Answer (score 1):

According to [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/site), since 1350 A.D. to 1400 A.D.:

> First recorded in 1350–1400; Middle English, from Middle French, from
> Latin *situs* “position, arrangement, site” (presumably originally,
> “leaving, setting down”), equivalent to *si-*, variant stem of *sinere*
> “to leave, allow to be” + *-tus* suffix of verbal action

You can find this information in many dictionaries by scrolling down past the definitions to a section titled "etymology," etymology being the history and origin of a word.